# Allocation of memory in numerical recipies c++

Tags: c++

In terms of allocation of memory:

let int a[i][j] = {matrix as below}

[image]

Now if I define the pointer *p = &a[0][0], then I can get a function
*(p +((o-1)*4+j-1)(where 4 stands for number of bits of int)

Hence a[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fFp6.jpg), which is in c++ since we start by 0 and not 1 equal to a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj7bT.jpg) 
*(p +((2-1)*4)+(2-1))=*(address of a +4+1) = 6 .

Now this makes sense to me, and hopefully it is correct, but please let me know if my reasoning is not.

**Next when reading the guide for numerical re.. I see this:**

[image]

**But the formula for the first method does not work as mine, what am I missing?**
[image]

**now in the second case when we create a double pointer **a, which is a list of pointers where each element points to a row? is it a row or is it a column it points to.**

Because if it is a row then I get confused when allocating memory in the way as below:

```
int rows;
int columns;
double **correls=Null;

for(int i=0;i<columns;i++){correls[i]= new double [columns];}
```

I just dont get why we are counting from i to columns -1, as i believed we have a column of pointers as in the photo at the bottom, and we need each element in row in that vector of pointers, to point to a new vector of elements, hence why not correls[rows] instead of counting of columns. I understand that we allocate a new vector as such new double [columns] as each pointer in the vector of pointer points to a specific vector of elements which have the number of columns as defined below.

Appreciate all the help I can get!

Thank you:)

Comment: 1. Arrays are 0-based in C++ 2. Please don't use raw arrays, use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead

Comment: int usually has way more bits than 4. I don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: _"where `4` stands for number of bits of `int`"_: You mean bytes. And what is `o` in your first "function"? And "a1" and "a2" are meant to be `a[1]` and `a[2]`?

Comment: Why are you reading a C guide and writing in C++? It's going to mislead you.

Comment: Nothing in quoted material is relevant to C++. You solve the problem by not using C-style arrays.

Answer (score 1):

There are two sensible ways of creating a 2D array in C

```
int array[4][5];
```

and

```
int **array;
array = malloc(4 * sizeof(int *));
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  array[i] = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

Now one of the glitches or quirks of C is that the syntax for aaddressing these two arrays is the same

```
array[i][j] = x;
```

Numerical Recipes was originally written in Fortran and by people who were mathematicians rather than programmers. So they bring a rather Fortran-centric view to the code.

In C++, it's normal to use a vector for automatic memory management and bounds checking. However the algorithmic heart of a complex program is often written in C, or C++ which is effectively C, because of the C++ overheads. Numerical Recipes gives you what will often be the algorithmic heart.

Answer (score 0):

> now in the second case when we create a double pointer **a, which is a list of pointers where each element points to a row?

You can decide that the pointed arrays are rows, yes.

> is it a row or is it a column it points to.

Remember that `a` is a pointer to the first element of an array. If you've decided that the arrays pointed by the elements of the array represent rows, then `a` points to the first of the pointers to rows.

> I just dont get why we are counting from i to columns -1, as i believed we have a column of pointers

Clearly, the person who wrote that code decided that each element of `correls` points to an array that represents a column. Therefore you have a pointer to an array of columns which are arrays of pointers that point to rows.

---

To conclude: There are two ways to represent a 2D array: Row major order, and column major order. Each is a transpose of the other.

---

PS. Do not allocate dynamic memory manually in C++. Instead use RAII containers such as `std::vector`. Also, be wary when reading C guides. They are going to lead you astray, for example by suggesting manual memory allocation.

PPS. Don't take heed of this quote:

> there is no multiplication; an additional indirection replaces it. We thus have, in general, a faster and more versatile scheme than the previous one

It's bogus: An indirection may require a memory access which is quadzillion times slower than multiplication. Versatility of dynamically adjustable size is the advantage of arrays of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: in C++, high level operations should never use raw pointers nor raw arrays. They should always be included (hidden) is classes that are cleanly used in OO mode through constructors, destructors and methods. So the remaining of this answer assumes that you a building a specialized container in which you may use low level operations.

Your initial example uses an existing 2D array and just *badly* allocates an array of pointers to the rows. But it is poor code:

- if C you should **never** cast the resul of malloc
- if C++ you should not use malloc at all

But anyway a dynamic allocation is a rather complex operation that involves a ancilliary work to find which piece of actual memory to use, mark it as used, store the allocated length for later use at freeing time, eventually maintain the list of free blocks, etc.

So you should avoid to allocate one row at a time. It is semantically correct but is an inefficient algorithm. It is much better to use one single big allocation for the whole array, even if you intend to use it through pointers - it is mainly important if you are building a custom container that could be used in many places.

You end with the following possible (low level) C++ codes:

- allocate one row at a time (inefficient but correct):

  ```
  int rows;
  int columns;
  double **correls;

  // set rows and columns at their values...

  correls = new (double *)[rows];
  for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) correls[i] = new double[colums];

  // you can now safely use correls[i][j] with 0<=i<rows and 0<=j<columns
  ```
- allocate a big 1D array in one single operation:

  ```
  int rows;
  int columns;
  double **correls;

  // set rows and columns at their values...

  correls = new (double *)[rows];
  _array = new double[rows * columns];
  for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) correls[i] = _array + i * columns; // or &(_array[i * columns])

  // you can now safely use correls[i][j] with 0<=i<rows and 0<=j<columns
  ```

Those ways allow you to allocate dynamic array whose sizes are only known at run time. Remember, even if they are accepted as extensions by common compilers, Variable Length Arrays are not supported by standard C++...

Comment: For low level C++ you should check out the [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) and the [Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines). The GSL as some useful, 0-overhead, classes (like ``owner<T>``, ``not_null<T>``, ``*_view``) designed to be used when interfacing with C or with low level C++.